# Wicket- RequiredFieldValidator for AjaxEditableLabel

Tags: java, wicket

At first I want to say, although RequiredFieldValidator is used in .NET but I use this term for wicket as I want to mean a Label (color: red and text: *) which will be be displayed beside AjaxEditableLabel when the editor of the AjaxEditableLabel will be blank. I have set AjaxEditableLabel.setRequired(true) and it is working, i.e., the Form cannot be submitted. But I am not able to track that red star Label beside the AjaxEditableLabel. What I did so far is :

```
private class TaskTypeSettingsForm extends Form {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 10058L;        
    private FeedbackMessageFilter filter;

    public TaskTypeSettingsForm(String id) {
        super(id);
        FeedbackPanel feedback = new FeedbackPanel("feedback");
        filter = new FeedbackMessageFilter();
        feedback.setFilter(filter);
        add(feedback);

        setOutputMarkupId(true);            
        final TaskTypeSettingsFormModel taskTypeSettingsFormModel = new TaskTypeSettingsFormModel();

        IModel model = new BoundCompoundPropertyModel(taskTypeSettingsFormModel);
        setModel(model);

        final WebMarkupContainer div = new WebMarkupContainer("div");
        div.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        final ListView listView = new ListView("listView", new PropertyModel(taskTypeSettingsFormModel, "taskTypeList")) {

            @Override
            protected void populateItem(ListItem item) {
                final String value = (String) item.getModelObject();
                final int index = item.getIndex();
                final Label star = new Label("star", "*");      
                //this label is always displaying, I need to 
                //display it when the editor is blank and hide when 
                //it contain valid text         
                star.setOutputMarkupId(true);
                final AjaxEditableLabel label = new AjaxEditableLabel("value", new Model(value)) {

                    @Override
                    public void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                        super.onSubmit(target);
                                //here I also try to get the editor 
                                //and add a SimpleAttributeModifier 
                                //with a javaScript for onBlur 
                                //event, but that script is not 
                                //working as I am not able to 
                                //append that script to the 
                                //editor's existing ajax
                        String input = (String) getModelObject();
                        if (input != null) {                                
                            taskTypeSettingsFormModel.getTaskTypeList().set(index, input);                              
                        }                                                   
                    }                                                       
                };                  
                label.setRequired(true);    

                item.add(star);
                label.setOutputMarkupId(true);
                label.add(new SimpleAttributeModifier("style", "cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;"));
                label.add(new AbstractValidator() {

                    @Override
                    protected void onValidate(IValidatable validatable) {
                        String value = (String) validatable.getValue();
                        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
                        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(value);
                        if (!matcher.matches()) {
                            error(validatable);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected String resourceKey() {                    
                        return "task_type_settings_form.error.regexFailure";
                    }      
                });
                item.add(label);
                item.add(removeLink("removeLink", item));                   
                item.add(moveUpLink("up", item));
                item.add(moveDownLink("down", item));
            }
        };

        listView.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        listView.setReuseItems(true);
        div.add(listView);

        //some code     
    }

    @Override
    protected void validate() {
        filter.reset();
        super.validate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSubmit() {
        TaskTypeSettingsFormModel taskTypeSettingsFormModel = (TaskTypeSettingsFormModel) getModelObject();
        for (String str : taskTypeSettingsFormModel.getTaskTypeList()) {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope I can explain the scenario. Any information regarding this will be very helpful to me. Thank you.

Comment: FYI, you don't need to include "Wicket-" in your titles; on this site, tags serve that purpose. Also, we generally prefer not to use "hello/thanks" lines here. Hellos, in particular, take up space in question previews in search results.

Comment: @Lord Torgamus I will keep you suggestion in mind. I had included Wicket in the title as I used the term RequiredFieldValidator in my question and this term is not related to Java rather ASP.NET.

Comment: I think there is a `RequiredFieldValidator` (or similar) in every imaginable web technology :-)

Comment: @Sean Patrick Floyd I agreed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of having a label hanging around, you could do it with a behaviour

```
public class RequiredStarBevaviour extends AbstractBehavior {

@Override
public void beforeRender(final Component component) {
    super.beforeRender(component);
    if (component instanceof FormComponent<?>) {
        if (!((FormComponent<?>) component).checkRequired()) {
            component.getResponse()
                    .write("<span class='redclass'>*</span>");
        }
    }
}
```

}

This will run each time the component is rendered, it will check if its a form component and if the required check is not met it will render the star.

EDIT response to question:

```
final AjaxEditableLabel label = new AjaxEditableLabel("value",
                new Model(value)) {

            @Override
            protected FormComponent newEditor(final MarkupContainer parent,
                    final String componentId, final IModel model) {
                final FormComponent newEditor = super.newEditor(parent,
                        componentId, model);
                newEditor.add(new RequiredStarBevaviour());
                return newEditor;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSubmit(final AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                super.onSubmit(target);
                // here I also try to get the editor
                // and add a SimpleAttributeModifier
                // with a javaScript for onBlur
                // event, but that script is not
                // working as I am not able to
                // append that script to the
                // editor's existing ajax
                final String input = (String) getModelObject();
                if (input != null) {
                    taskTypeSettingsFormModel.getTaskTypeList().set(index,
                            input);
                }
            }
        };
```

Comment: @Tnem Thanks. So I can add this behavior to AjaxEditableLabel?. One thing I want to say, I added an AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior to that AjaxEditableLabel, but it was throwing exception telling that it can be added only to a FormComponent, is AjaxEditableLabel is a FormComponent?

Comment: @Tapas Bose No that is a Panel, but it contains a form component _editor_ so you can add that behaviour to `label.getEditor()`

Comment: @Tnem AjaxEditableLabel.getEditor() is a protected method. Isn't it? How can I invoke label.getEditor()?

Comment: @Tapas Bose True, you probably want to override the newEditor method and add it when the editor is created.

Comment: @Tnem I don't know how to override newEditor(), is it something like: super.newEditor(parent, componentId, model); FormComponent editor = getEditor(); editor.add(new RequiredStarBevaviour()); Is it right? Unfortunately I don't have my project in hand right now, so I am unable to test it and I am not able to find any example over internet regarding the overriding of newEditor() method. Thank you.

Comment: @Tapas Bose I've added the override to the code you provided in my answer.

Comment: @Tnem thank you very much. I will add this snippet and will let you know.

Comment: @Tnem why the double cast? Do you want to be really, really sure that the compiler knows it is a FormComponent? :)

Comment: @Tetsu no thats a facepalm :D

Comment: In the newEditor method there is return statement before the behaviour gets added...

Answer (score 1):

@Tnem your solution worked perfectly. After a little tweak what I did I am showing, it might be helpful to future users:

```
                AjaxEditableLabel taskTypeEditableLabel = new AjaxEditableLabel("taskTypeEditableLabel", new Model(value)) {

                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 10061L;

                    @Override
                    public void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                        super.onSubmit(target);
                        String input = (String) getModelObject();
                        if (input != null) {                                
                            taskTypeSettingsFormModel.getTaskTypeList().set(index, input);                              
                        }                                                   
                    }       

                    @Override
                    protected FormComponent newEditor(MarkupContainer parent, String componentId, IModel model) {
                        FormComponent editor = super.newEditor(parent, componentId, model);

                        editor.add(new AbstractBehavior() {                             

                            private static final long serialVersionUID = 10062L;

                            @Override
                            public void beforeRender(final Component component) {
                                super.beforeRender(component);
                                if (component instanceof FormComponent) {
                                    if (!((FormComponent) component).checkRequired()) {
                                        component.getResponse().write("<span style='color: red; margin-right: 5px;'>*</span>");
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onComponentTag(Component component, ComponentTag tag) {
                                super.onComponentTag(component, tag);
                                if (component instanceof FormComponent) {
                                    tag.put("style", "width: 400px");
                                    if (!((FormComponent) component).isValid()) {                                           
                                        tag.put("style", "width: 400px; border: 1px solid #CC2200;");                                           
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });

                        editor.add(new AbstractValidator() {

                            private static final long serialVersionUID = 10063L;

                            @Override
                            protected void onValidate(IValidatable validatable) {
                                String value = (String) validatable.getValue();
                                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([A-Z]+)((([\\w\\s-//]*)[\\w&&[^_]]+)?)");
                                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(value);
                                if (!matcher.matches()) {
                                    error(validatable);
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            protected String resourceKey() {                    
                                return "task_type_settings_form.error.regexFailure";
                            }
                        });
                        editor.setRequired(true);
                        return editor;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected Component newLabel(MarkupContainer parent, String componentId, IModel model) {
                        Component label = super.newLabel(parent, componentId, model);
                        label.add(new AbstractBehavior() {

                            private static final long serialVersionUID = 10064L;

                            @Override
                            public void onComponentTag(Component component, ComponentTag tag) {
                                super.onComponentTag(component, tag);
                                if (component instanceof Component) {
                                    tag.put("style", "cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;");
                                }
                            }                               
                        });

                        return label;
                    }

                };                              
                taskTypeEditableLabel.setOutputMarkupId(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

Set the `star` label as hidden on init:

```
star.setVisible(false);
```

When the form is submitted, show `star` based on `input` (and add to `AjaxRequestTarget`):

```
String input = (String) getModelObject(); // From your code
star.setVisible("".equals(input));
target.add(star); // Or is it addComponent()? Can't remember :-S
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. In onSubmit method I did if input is null or equals to "" then display alert. But After adding setRequired true to tha AJaxEditableLabel it stopped working. I can not get getModelObject anymore for vacant TextField.

Comment: @Tapas Bose That I cannot explain as it's been quite a while since I last had my hands on a Wicket project. It was worth a shot, but I really can't remember the internals of forms and validating behavior, I'm afraid.