# AjaxEditableLabel TextField size

Tags: java, ajax, wicket

How can I control the size (width + character limit) of the textfield that appears when clicking an AjaxEditableLabel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the method `newEditor` and add your own custom behavior, for example overriding the method `onTagComponent`.

There's a similar question here: [Wicket- RequiredFieldValidator for AjaxEditableLabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554717/wicket-requiredfieldvalidator-for-ajaxeditablelabel)