# Wicket How to add double inputvalidation to a AjaxEditableLabel

Tags: java, wicket

I'm having trouble to adding input validation for a double in wicket when useing an ajaxEditableLabel.
This is my code: (item is a listitem from a listview)

```
item.add(new AjaxEditableLabel("myDouble", new Model(myObject.getMyDouble())) {
                @Override
                protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                    super.onSubmit(target);
                    myObject.setMyDouble(new Double(getEditor().getInput())); //here it fails to read the input when a use enters a wrong number
                   //Do something when it's a double
                }
            });
```

**How can I add a validator to this component to check wheter this a double value?**

At the moment I'm using:

```
         Double.parseDouble(myval);
```

With try catch...
But this also needs the input string to be changed because of , and .

*There should be a wicket way to validate this input?*

Edit**:
Maybe I have to add NumericTextField to this component but I don't understand how.

Comment: Have you tried setting type to your component? `component.setType(Double.class);`

Comment: No, where should I set it? I taught it got the type from the model. I've tried setting it on the ajaxeditablelabel but it didn't work.

Comment: No, it doesn't get it from the generic used on the model. You have to set it like this: `foo = new AjaxEditableLabel(...); foo.setType(Double.class);`

Comment: K I've found it I guess I've used getConvertedInput() in combination with the setType stead...

Comment: Cool. Check this too, just in case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554717/wicket-requiredfieldvalidator-for-ajaxeditablelabel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this:

Java:

```
public class MyPage extends WebPage {

    private List<Double> list = Arrays.asList(2013.0, 100.500);

    public MyPage() {

        final FeedbackPanel feedback = new FeedbackPanel("feedback");
        feedback.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        add(feedback);

        ListView<Double> items = new ListView<Double>("items", new PropertyModel(this, "list")) {
            @Override
            protected void populateItem(ListItem<Double> item) {
                item.add(new AjaxEditableLabel("item", item.getModel()) {
                    @Override
                    protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list.toArray()));
                        target.add(feedback);
                        super.onSubmit(target);
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onError(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                        target.add(feedback);
                        super.onError(target);
                    }
                }.add(new IValidator<Object>() {
                    @Override
                    public void validate(IValidatable<Object> validatable) {
                        String in = String.valueOf(validatable.getValue());
                        try {
                            Double.parseDouble(in.replace(".", ","));
                        } catch (Exception ignore) {
                            try{
                                Double.parseDouble(in.replace(",", "."));
                            }catch (Exception e){
                                ValidationError error = new ValidationError(String.format("`%s` is not a Double", in));
                                validatable.error(error);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }));
            }
        };
        add(items);
    }
}
```

Markup:

```
<div wicket:id="feedback"/>
<ul wicket:id="items">
    <li wicket:id="item"></li>
</ul>
```

---

The validator above made just for demonstration, in real code I suggest to create a separate class (not an anonimous class).

Answer (score 1):

I solved by changing getInput to **getConvertedInput();** This was my old way of solving it.
Using **getModelObject()** is better and since the Type is set to Double this is better.

I've also changed the type to Double. **.setType(Double.class**

```
item.add(new AjaxEditableLabel("myDouble", new Model(myObject.getMyDouble())) {
            @Override
            protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                super.onSubmit(target);
                myObject.setMyDouble((Double)getEditor().getModelObject())); //changes here!!!
               //Do something when it's a double
            }
        }.setType(Double.class));
```

Comment: Now that the validator only allow Double values, use `getEditor(). getModelObject()` instead of `getConvertedInput()`